# Join/Snap Objects. Remove border line Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Absolute newbie.

Trying to snap two objects which are mirror images of each other. The problem is I am seeing a thin vertical line ? Want to get rid of that. I don't want to do union because I want to change the color of each object. i verified the alignment and ensured that there is no extra-space because of alignment issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because of antialising when rendering the vectors to display them on a computer screen. It also happens in other vector image editors, such as Illustrator, so it's not a problem that's specific to Inkscape.

One method to fix it is to add a thin stroke to the shapes, the same colour as the fill, then a tiny overlap happens automatically, but without having to move anything.

Answer (score 2):

Inkscape make exactly fitting seams partially transparent. The same unwanted behaviour is common in many vector drawing programs. The plus is that seams do not look out jaggy.

To kill the light add something under the seam - a stroke or stretch another of the shapes. It causes no harm if the added part has the same color as one of the face to face shapes.

Comment: Okay. Moved one of the shapes to over-lap instead of exact snap. That took care of it. Thanks for your help.